# Subversion: Can't move... Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, svn, svnserve

Whilst trying to commit some files to SVN, we're suddenly all getting this error

```
    Can't move '/usr/local/svn/articles/db/txn-protorevs/2002-8.rev' 
to '/usr/local/svn/articles/db/revs/2/2003': Permission denied
```

I checked the permissions in the repository, and they look the same as all our other repositories, yet this is the only repo that causes the error.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

SVN is running as root on Linux via svnserve, FWIW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the repositories I manage, the repository contents themselves are owned by apache:apache. Trying to do something as `root` without using `sudo -u apache` usually creates this situation for me. A good `chown -R apache.apache {repo root}` will usually fix it, as you indicated.

My guess is that you performed some function via the filesystem as someone other than root.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we were just missing group write permissions on some of the subdirectories in the remote repository (revs, transactions, etc.) Still not sure how they got mucked up in the first place, though.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the SVN is started with the same user as the repository has been created.